# Exporting as JAR messes with file paths in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, export

I've run into a problem with my res folder when exporting my project into a runnable jar. everything works fine, all assets from res/graphics are loaded, and in res/save there are two level files. When testing it in eclipse it searches the res/save folder and finds them both, but it cannot find anything when exported even though the files are in the same place.

Tree

```
master
|-bin
|-res
  |-img
    |-[Image assets]
  |-save
    |-level1.mix
    |-level2.mix
  |-sound
    |-[sound assets]
|-src
  |-com
    |-kruhlmann
      |-towerdefense
        |-Component.java <- main file
        |-[Other files and folders]
```

Comment: How are you loading the resources?

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files so you can't use the files APIs